# How to get rid of duplicated values in LEFT JOIN SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have a comments table with parent and child comments having the following fields

```
comments
    comment_id
    parent_id
    thread_id (Foreign Key)
    title
    body
    comment_date
    user_name
```

I want to sort out the comments in this form that first appear the parent comment then its child comments and then next parent comment and then its child comments

I am using the following query

```
SELECT c1 . * , c2 . * 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL 
AND c1.thread_id =122
```

It is giving the following ouput
[image]

You can see that there are so many duplicated rows in the first table

I want the following ouput

[image]

You can see that in this ouput, first comes the parent comment (having NULL in parent_id), then its child comments and then the next parent comment and then its child comments.

How can I form my SQL Query to get this output. 
Note: (The second picture is not the result of any query, I have modified it to just clear my point of view and to tell you that what kind of ouput I want.)

Comment: You want distinct comments?

Comment: @chandresh_cool there is no distinct issue in this. Actually it is sorting issue. I want to sort out in this form that first come the parent comment then all of its child comments and so on.

Comment: Just you need to select particular recored instead of c1.* ,C2.* and some order by clause your data will look like the way you want

Comment: @RashidFarooq But using Group By you will not get duplicate records if you are going with your query otherwise try some alternative way...

Answer (score 3):

None of the rows are duplicates, it's just that the `c1` comment gets selected repeatedly because it is ostensibly the parent of many `c2` comments.  It sounds like you actually want two *separate* queries.

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_id IS NULL AND thread_id = 122
UNION
SELECT c2.* FROM comments c1 JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL AND c1.thread_id =122
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1 . *
FROM comments c1
RIGHT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c1.parent_id IS NULL 
AND c1.thread_id =122
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1 . * , c2 . * 
FROM comments c1
LEFT JOIN comments c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.comment_id
WHERE c2.parent_id IS NOT NULL 
AND c1.thread_id = 122
```

I created table and tested with the above query ,it works fine for me.If the above doesn't work fine for you,then please export the comment table and post here .I'll send the exact query.

Once again ,if it is in cakephp, then use 'threaded' in the find query ,which always works fine for parent-child type table structure in database.

Waiting for the response...

Comment: I have tried this query but it does not give the desired results. Here is the structure of my comments table

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `body` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `date_comment` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12